# Getting Child in AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I really dont understand what im doing wrong here. So what im doing is Im trying to get the post values of the specific user as descriped in picture

[image]

So to get the Users Post i used this:

```
app.controller('chatController', ["$scope", 'AuthService', "Auth", "Ref", "$rootScope","$firebaseArray",
    function($scope, AuthService, Auth, Ref, $rootScope, $firebaseArray) {

        console.log(AuthService.User.email)//Gives me correct Email
        console.log(AuthService.User.password)//Gives me correct password
        console.log(AuthService.User.uid)//Gives me correct uid
        console.log(AuthService.User.username)//Gives me correct username

var some = $firebaseArray(Ref.child("Posts").child(AuthService.User.username)); //Why Giving me an error here when i put that child in?
console.log((some))
 var postsFirebase = $firebaseArray(Ref)
                $scope.messages = postsFirebase

        $scope.submit = function() {
            if (!($scope.textValue)) {
                //Checking for empty string
            } else {
                alert($scope.textValue)

                Ref.child("Posts").child(AuthService.User.username).push({ 
                    "Posts": $scope.textValue 
                })



            }

        }
    }
])
```

When i put the child in on 9th line of AuthService.User.username it gives me an error saying:

> Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "null". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

**My main problem here is getting the data from the child. Thankyou**
Please help me. Thankyou!

Comment: If you *hardcode* the username like `Ref.child("Posts").child("GREE")`, does the problem disappear?